# Circular permutations and irreducible permutation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, permutations

On a book I'm studying I found this problem: say when a permutation matrix is irreducible. According to the solution provided a permutation matrix is irreducible if and only if it is associated to a circular permutation, so that there are $(n-1)!$ irreducible permutation matrices of order n. But how can we say that a permutation is circular? If I'm not wrong, since they are equivalence classes, you can only count circuar permutations, bu you can't say if a permutation is circular. And if the solution refers to one representative of each equivalence class, which one she is refering to?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say a permutation is an equivalence class. You can [edit] the question to include the solution and point explicitly to the part that confuses you.

Comment: Circular permutations are equivalence classes. If you have two permutations such that one is a cyclic permutation of the other, then they are equivalent, and you count them only once. [Circular permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Circular_permutations) are defined as the ways you can dispose n elements on the circle, by only considering the relative positions of the elements.

Comment: This may be a language issue. They mean permutations that consist of a single cycle (of which there are $(n-1)!$), not what Wikipedia calls "circular permutations".

Comment: @joriki Yes, you're probably right. Do you know some proof? Is there any connection between circular permutations and single cycles? They first introduce the circular permutations and the cyclic permutations, and then call circular permutations the single cycle permutations.